# How to merge two different web applications

Tags: asp.net-mvc, master-pages

We have 2 different ASP.NET applications.
One Application should show specific information(A) and the other one should show other information(B).  Both applications are from different developers. One ist MVC(A) and the other one is Asp.net(B). 
Now I want to add a menu in B application to control the A application. So if i click on one button, a frame in the application should changed with the Url of the A applation.
Our problem is that we can't merge the code.

I don't want to use IFrames.

Comment: You should clarify what you mean by "run one application in the other"

Comment: I think you are going to need to provide a lot more detail about what "run one application in the other" means to you before anyone can give you a meaningful answer...

Answer (score 1):

Maybe look into virtual directories in IIS

http://support.microsoft.com/kb/172138